# Implementing soft delete with minimal impact on performance and code

Tags: sql, soft-delete

There are some [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241071/deleting-database-records-unpermenantley-soft-delete) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020568/soft-delete-best-practices-php-mysql) on the topic, but they are not really helping me.

I want to implement a soft delete feature like on StackOverflow, where items are not really deleted, but just hidden. I am using a SQL database. Here are 3 options:

- Add a `is_deleted` boolean field.

  - Advantages: Simple.
  - Disadvantages: No date record. Forces me to add a `is_deleted = 0` in every query.
- Add a `deleted_date` date field. This is set to `NULL` if it's not deleted.

  - Advantages: Has date.
  - Disadvantages: Still cluttering my queries.

For both of the above

- It will also impact performance because there are all these useless rows. They still have to be maintained in indexes. Also an index on the `deleted` column won't help when fetching non-deleted (the majority) of the rows. Full table scan is needed.

Another option is to create a separate table to hold deleted items:

- Advantages: Improved performance when querying non-deleted rows. No need to add conditions to my queries on non-deleted rows. Easier on index maintenance.
- Disadvantages: Complexity: Requires data migration for both deletion and undeletion. Need for new tables. Referential integrity is harder to handle.

Is there a better option?

Comment: What RDBMS?  There might be database level tricks that can aid in your endeavor

Comment: I was looking for an agnostic solution, although Oracle, SQL Server and Postgres are preferred - in that order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the key is numeric, I handle a "soft-delete" by negating the key.  (Of course, won't work for identity keys).   You don't need to change your code at all, and can easily restore the record by multiplying by -1.

Just another approach to give some thought to...   If the key is alphanumeric, you can do something similar by prepending a unique "marker" characters.  Since deleted records will all begin with this marker, then will end up off by themselves in the index.

Comment: what do you mean by "You don't need to change your code at all"? Won't you still have to check the sign of the key?

Comment: Perhaps a better comment was, you don't need to change your database table's structure at all.  Sorry for any confusion

Comment: Also this amount to using a magic number type logic which is ugly design - not easy to document and maintain

Answer (score 3):

I personally would base my answer off of how often you anticipate your users wanting to access that deleted data or "restore" that deleted data.

If it's often, then I would go with a "Date_Deleted" field and put a calculated "IsDeleted" in my poco in the code.

If it's never (or almost never) then a history table or deleted table is good for the benefits you explained.

I personally almost never use deleted tables (and opt for isDeleted or date_deleted) because of the potential risk to referencial integrity.  You have A -> B and you remove the record from B database... You now have to manage referencial integrity because of your design choice.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, the best way forward, when thinking about scaling and eventual table/database sizes is your third option - a separate table for deleted items. Such a table can eventually be moved to a different database to support scaling.

I believe you have listed the three most common options. As you have seen, each has advantages and disadvantages. Personally, I like taking the longer view on things.

Answer (score 2):

I think your analysis of the options is good but you missed a few relevant points which I list below. Almost all implementations that I have seen use some sort of deleted or versioning field on the row as you suggest in  your first two options.

**Using one table with deleted flag:**
If your indexes all contain the deleted flag field first and your query's mostly contain a where isdeleted=false type structure then it DOES solve you performance problems and the indexes very efficiently exclude the deleted rows. Similar logic could be used for the deleted date option.

**Using two Tables**
In general you need to make massive changes to reports because some reports may refer to deleted data (like old sales figures might refer to a deleted sales category). One can overcome this by creating a view which is a union of the two tables to read from and only write to the active records table.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose we create a field called `dead` to mark deleted rows. We can create a index where field `dead` is false.
In this way, we only search non-deleted rows using the hint use index.